How does knowing a non-negative integers solutions for some Diophantine equation yield a negative, zero or positive integers solution?
Here is how my textbook by Marin Davis introduces a famous Hibert's 10th problem:

For suppose we could solve the problem for
nonnegative integral solutions. Then, to determine whether or not
$P(x_l, ... ,x_n) = 0$ has a solution in integers, positive, negative, or
zero, it clearly suffices to test for nonnegative integral solutions each of
the $2^n$ equations.
$$
P(x_l, x_2, ... , x_n) = 0,
P(-x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = 0,
...,
P(-x_1, -x_2, ..., -x_n) = 0
$$

I can't convince myself this method works for every possible Diophantine equation (which by definitions demands $P$ to be a polynomial). Why can't exist some solution with at least one $x^{neg}_i$ being a negative integer while also not being a negation of the corresponding $x^{pos}_i$ from the positive solution (given by assumption)?

The problem is not whether a given polynomial $P$ has a solution in integers, but whether it can be determined if any given $P$ does. Now assume that for any given $P$ there exists an algorithm that determines whether it has non-negative solutions, then you can also determine whether a given polynomial, let's call it $Q$ to avoid confusion, has integer solutions: namely if any of the $2^n$ (generally different) polynomials that are obtained by replacing any subset of the $x_i$ by $-x_i$ has a solution in non-negative integers; if none of them do, there is none.

So the whole idea that we try every new $Q$ derived from the original arbitrary $P$ and apply the same method for solving it with negative integers only. If one is found for, say, $P(-x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ from the OP, then $x_1$ is a negative integer by the definition and thus doubly-negated, which at the end yields a positive integer. Is that right?

Yes, except that probably you meant non-negative: if you find a solution in non-negative integers for $P(-x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, you found one with $x_2,\ldots,x_n$ non-negative and $x_1$ non-positive for your original $P$. Doing the same for all combinations of signs of the $x_i$, you will find all integer solutions, positive, negative and zero.
